# Set visibility of Context Menu Items in WPF depending on other menu items

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have a tree view control with hierarchical data. It has a context menu with four options: Expand, Expand All, Collapse, Collapse All. I am currently using the following class to show / hide the context menu items:

```
Public Class clsTreeContextMenuVisibilityConverter
Implements IValueConverter

Public Function Convert(InValue As Object, InTargetType As Type, InParameter As Object, InCulture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert


    Dim node As TreeNode = Nothing

    If InValue Is Nothing Then
        Return Binding.DoNothing
    End If

    node = DirectCast(InValue, TreeNode)

    If InValue.[GetType]() <> GetType([Boolean]) Then
        If node.HasChildren AndAlso node.ParentNode Is Nothing Then 
            If node.IsExpanded Then
                Return Visibility.Collapsed
            End If              
            Return Visibility.Visible
        End If
    End If

    Return Binding.DoNothing

End Function

Public Function ConvertBack(InValue As Object, InTargetType As Type, InParameter As Object, InCulture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
End Function
```

End Class

XAML:

```
<Style  x:Key="ExpandMenuItemStyle"
    TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource VisConverter}}" />
</Style>

 <MenuItem Header="Expand" Style="{StaticResource ExpandMenuItemStyle}" />
```

VisConverter is x:Key of the converter class. My question is, if a Node is expanded, I should see Collapse and vice versa. Also, if it is a root parent level node, then I should see Expand All. So do I have to write separate converters for all four cases or is there an intelligent way to do this?

Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want two converters or two pairs of converters. One for the expanded state and one for returning whether the node is a parent or child. If you go for just two converters you will need a parameter to determine whether the converter should return `Visibility.Visible` or `Visibility.Collapsed`.

With four converters you won't need the parameter.

Comment: I did not exactly use two converters, but your answer gave me an idea to pass menu item name as ConverterParameter, then I could handle all four cases in just one converter class.